# how to use the /execute command to make it so if a mob has a radius to another mob it will execute a /summon command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So to explain this. Im trying to make it so if a player places a tnt minecart. And if any player, mob or animal is at the maximum distance of 1 it will summon a primed tnt. But every time i try to do it, it either lags my entire game with tnt explosions or only executes if the command block has a certain radius of what i inputted.

Answer (score 2):

You should test that the minecart doesn't have a tag, then give it a tag and summon the primed tnt. This way it will only summon once
Another option is to kill the minecart

For the commands it depends on your version of minecraft, I will assume 1.13, if you are in 1.12 let me know

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:tnt_minecart,tag=!exploded] at @s if entity @e[distance=..1,limit=1] run function explode
```

Which calls this function

```
# explode.mcfunction
tag @s add exploded
summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! could you exapnd you your answer by providing steps on how OP might tag the TNT and summon a primed tnt?

Comment: I certainly can, although I don't like just giving people the commands (I'm a verified helper on the minecraft commands discord, and on there we have a policy of first explaining the logic first, and only if they can't figure out the commands from that then we start giving commands.
(I'll start writing the commands now)

Comment: Done, commands added

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it is good to have some more people who can write and explain Minecraft commands around! One thing to keep in mind though when answering is that you aren't just writing an answer for the OP. Arqade is also a reference that lots of other people might come to to get their answers, so full and complete answers tend to do a lot better. That isn't to say that every question should be answered, but generally un-researched/lazy  questions just get down-voted and eventually closed.